# ubuntu desktops lost while updating

Tags: unity, gnome, upgrade

I've had Ubuntu 12.03 w/Unity desktop installed on my computer along with Gnome 2 and XBMC desktops which I used occasionally. In attempting to upgrade Gnome 2 to Gnome 3, I inadvertently wiped out all my desktops and now only seem to have the option of formating the drive in order to reinstall Unity or Gnome. I don't want to lose my prior installation and all the files I have on the drive. I can access the files when using the Gnome 3 live flash drive but I don't have the permissions I need to recover my important files and/or transfer them to another drive.

I hope someone can assist me by advising how I can go about reinstalling Unity without wiping out my drive and all my files.

Comment: Can you still access a terminal? If you do, then run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: So? Did it work for you this is why you disappeared?

Comment: Why you suddenly stopped nagging? If I helped say something otherwise say what happened!

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal using (ctrl+alt+T), and try to reset compiz and unity by:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools    
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/       
unity-reset
setsid unity
```

If you are still facing it, then open terminal again and reinstall desktop and unity

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

**UPDATE**

From the live CD, open terminal window and type this command

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

You will get some results like

```
/dev/sda1 Linux
/dev/sda2 Etendue
/dev/sdb3 Linux swap / Solaris
```

The one you want is the Linux one. Next step you have to try to repare it. First we will go with this fdisk command. It should repair it. After you are done reboot and try to use the old system

```
sudo fsck.ext3 -f /dev/sda1
```

Comment: I tried both of the above to no avail. I'm acceessing the  terminal from my startup flash drive as my computer won't boot normally.It hangs up in bash and give me a 'initramf" prompt.

Comment: That is it hangs up in ash and gives me and "initramfs" prompt. When I access the terminal I'm doing so from my live installation flash drive. Any other suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what you are exactly doing. I would suggest then don't waste your time and reinstall the OS ;)

Comment: If I try to boot up normally the pc won't boot, it hangs up after a few seconds and gives me a message that the boot files are not found. I get a prompt that says, "initramfs." In order to boot up the computer I have to use a installation flash drive w

Comment: When I use the try ubuntu without installing option I can access my hard drive and read the files but I lack the permission to move them to another drive so that I can reinstall ubuntiu. I'm trying not to lose all my phtos, videos, etc.

Comment: If someone could take another look at this and assist me I would be very appreciative. I need info on how I can reinstall my ubuntu gnome or unity on my hard drive fro a flash drive

Comment: First you can't configure an installed system from a flash drive. That means you running the commands I wrote can't be done in a terminal from flash drive. They are two different systems. What you have to do is to repair the corrupted boot from the terminal in your live disk. I am not sure if you are able to do this but let's give it a shot. I will update the answer and you write results in the comment.

Comment: If you can post screen shots for every step it will be more helpful